# Does CUDA use an interpreter or a compiler?

Tags: cuda

This is a bit of silly question, but I'm wondering if CUDA uses an interpreter or a compiler?
I'm wondering because I'm not quite sure how CUDA manages to get source code to run on two cards with different compute capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA):

> Programmers use 'C for CUDA' (C with Nvidia extensions and certain restrictions), compiled through a PathScale Open64 C compiler.

So, your answer is: **it uses a compiler.**

And to touch on the reason it can run on multiple cards ([source](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-faq)):

> CUDA C/C++ provides an abstraction, it's a means for you to express how you want your program to execute. The compiler generates PTX code which is also not hardware specific. At runtime the PTX is compiled for a specific target GPU - this is the responsibility of the driver which is updated every time a new GPU is released.

Comment: It is worth noting that recent CUDA uses an elf based fat binary format for GPU code objects, and an executable can contain final assembler for multiple architectures within the same application. So often no driver recompilation of PTX code is required, the runtime libraries just select the appropriate code object from the fat binary payload.

Answer (score 0):

These official documents [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) and [The CUDA Compiler Driver (NVCC)](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/nvcc.pdf) explain all the details about the compilation process.

From the second document:

> nvcc mimics the behavior of the GNU compiler gcc: it accepts a range
>   of conventional compiler options, such as for defining macros and
>   include/library paths, and for steering the compilation process.

Answer (score 0):

Not just limited to  cuda , shaders in directx or opengl  are also   complied to some kind of byte code  and converted to native code  by the underlying driver.