# Parallel compilers in GPU

Tags: compiler-construction, parallel-processing, gpu

For my term paper, I am required to study how parallel compilers esp those used in GPUs perform task mapping and the various heuristics used to perform data mapping/alignment.

Any pointers to papers covering existing literature, new trends would be immensely helpful and appreciated.

Best,
Subramanian

Comment: [Does CUDA use an interpreter or a compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612058/does-cuda-use-an-interpreter-or-a-compiler/10612172)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVIDIA now uses the open-source LLVM compiler for CUDA. You will find [here](http://llvm.org/pubs/) LLVM related publications.

Comment: I was able to find a publication which talks about managing GPU-CPU communication management, my instructor keeps stressing on communication patterns. 
Thank you that link will be of immense help for other compiler things I am interested in also.